# Laravel query by custom attribute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have a question pertaining querying an eloquent model using a custom attribute.

I have a class/model `Item` and i have created an attribute:

```
  function getWeeklySalesCountAttribute()
  {
     return rand(3, 1000); //real logic is in db
  }
```

So in my controller I want to pick items that have the highest weekly sales first and paginate them

```
    $items = Item::where(function($item){
        //find the items with highest weekly sales
    })->paginate(10);
```

How do i achieve that given I manage to pull the `$item->weekly_sales_count` attribute

Comment: I am not sure though. but so far I guess, is class 'item' your eloquent class or normal classs?

Comment: Its an Eloquent class (a model)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Eloquent, you need use a filter.

```
 $result = Model::get()->filter(function($item) {
    return $item->weekly_sales_count > 3;
 });
```

Comment: thanks, let me try it but the mission is to filter the ones with the highest sales and paginate them, so whats the proper way of using filter. If you can link me to where ```filter``` is explained i will be so happy