# How do i use Laravel query an object based on an attribute (accessor) condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I use Accessor for my Model

```
public function getStatusAttribute($value) {
   switch ($value) {
      case 1:
         return 'Active';
         break;
      default:
         return 'Nonactive';
         break;
   }
}
```

How can I run a whereRaw based on a value? something like this:

if

```
$search = 'act';
```

```
$user = User::whereRaw("status like '%$search%'");
```

Is there a way to do this?

I expected, i can get User Data with status by searching similar **'active'** or **'nonactive'** , not **'0'** or **'1'**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eloquent search/where on custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020053/eloquent-search-where-on-custom-attributes)

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569604/laravel-query-by-custom-attribute

Comment: let me try the answer

Comment: I don't think that's what I meant

Comment: make a select filter for active and nonactive and avoid this weird solution.

Comment: I mean this is just a small example for easy understanding

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do this exactly.

The database does not know about your custom attribute so you will need to do the filtering after all the items come back from the database or do the search yourself in code first.  This is what was suggested in the comments.